# Spark Streaming is not streaming,but waits showing consumer-config values

Tags: spark-streaming

I am trying to stream data using `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` artifact and 2.1.1 version along with `spark-streaming_2.11` version 2.1.1 and kafka_2.11(0.10.2.1 version).

When I start the program, Spark is not streaming data and neither it is throwing any error.

Below is my code, dependencies, and response.

Dependencies:

```
 "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.1",
 "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.1.1"
```

Code:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("kafka-dstream").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "ec2-xx-yy-zz-abc.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> ("java-test-consumer-" + random.nextInt()+"-" + 
System.currentTimeMillis()),
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )

val topics = Array("test")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
    ssc,
    PreferConsistent,
    Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
stream.foreachRDD(f=>f.foreachPartition(f=>f ->{
                    while (f.hasNext) {                            
  System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+f.next().key());
    }
}))

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Response (Logs):

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from D:\Scala_Workspace\LM\project
[info] Set current project to LM (in build file:/D:/Scala_Workspace/LM/)
[info] Running consumer.One
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.1.1
17/06/09 12:43:44 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: ee208961
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: ee208961
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
17/06/09 12:43:44 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(ee208961); groups wi
 permissions: Set(ee208961); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 51695.
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\EE208961\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-7f3c43f0-d1f5-43fb-b185-a5bf78de4496
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 93.3 MB
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/06/09 12:43:45 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.1.22.70:4040
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 51706.
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.1.22.70:51706
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.1.22.70, 51706, None)
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.1.22.70:51706 with 93.3 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.1.22.70, 51706,
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.1.22.70, 51706, None)
17/06/09 12:43:46 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.1.22.70, 51706, None)
17/06/09 12:43:46 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding enable.auto.commit to false for executor
17/06/09 12:43:46 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding auto.offset.reset to none for executor
17/06/09 12:43:46 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding executor group.id to spark-executor-sadad
17/06/09 12:43:46 WARN KafkaUtils: overriding receive.buffer.bytes to 65536 see KAFKA-3135
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Slide time = 5000 ms
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Remember interval = 5000 ms
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO DirectKafkaInputDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.DirectKafkaInputDStream@5cda65c2
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ForEachDStream: Slide time = 5000 ms
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ForEachDStream: Storage level = Serialized 1x Replicated
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ForEachDStream: Checkpoint interval = null
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ForEachDStream: Remember interval = 5000 ms
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ForEachDStream: Initialized and validated org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream@1b9c49ce
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
        metric.reporters = []
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        bootstrap.servers = [ec2-54-69-23-196.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:9092]
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        enable.auto.commit = false
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        interceptor.classes = null
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        client.id =
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        max.poll.records = 2147483647
        check.crcs = true
        request.timeout.ms = 40000
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        group.id = sadad
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.key.password = null
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        session.timeout.ms = 30000
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        auto.offset.reset = latest

17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.2.1
17/06/09 12:43:47 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
```

The code starts waiting here,neither it throws error,nor streams.

And what else i observed is,if i don't use "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.2.1" dependency, am getting

```
"Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.types.SchemaException: Error reading field 'topic_metadata': Error reading array of size 291941, only 32 bytes available" error,
```

so i used kafka_2.11(0.10.2.1 version) dependency.

Comment: If you go to the Spark UI, on the Streaming Tab, do you see data coming into the stream?

Comment: Hello maasg,thak you for your response,i have edited my code,please have a look at it,and as per you asked,in the Spark UI code,i don't see Streaming Tab at all and even Job,Stage and Storage are also blank.

Comment: For such streaming behaviour,am doubtful as to whether its dependency issue or any spark-kafka configuration issue.Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Are you running in a VM?  could you try `local[4]` instead of `local[*]` ?  For the rest, I don't see something wrong with the code.

Comment: No maasg,am running in my local system,and its dual core,and i tried using local[4],still the same behaviour.

Comment: You could do `stream.print()` instead of `foreachRDD` to further reduce the minimal test. Also try a local kafka. (a quick docker image would do) to reduce the surface of the test. Reduce until it works and then broaden it again.

Comment: Tried with stream.print() maasg,no luck.And i don't think its kafka problem to try with docker,because my other producer and consumer codes are running properly.

Comment: An additional idea would be to do a thread dump to check what the driver is doing

Comment: I got it resolved with Mr Yuval Itzchakov's help.From the code point,its flaw free,but the mistake was in my installation.For me to get topic name along with messages,i haD to use "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.1.1" dependency,but i had installed kafka 0.8.2.1 in my cluster,hence when i was trying to consume messages,it was neither throwing error nor streaming data,but when upgraded kafka to kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1 in my cluster,it began streaming data as expected.So basically it was version conflict between my installation and build.sbt file.Thank you Yuval and maasg.

Comment: @Ishwar_Tej, Could you pls elaborate on upgrading Kafka. Because I'm using HDP with "kafka_2.10-0.10.1.2" and tried to provide "streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10" as dependency. But still facing the same issue.